# How to achieve Bulk Editing in Material-Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Bulk Editing is a requested feature, but the current [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) library only has the option to open multiple edits but will only edit one row at a time, how would I be able to achieve bulk editing? Editing multiple rows at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating a state that will handle the selected rows, using the `onSelectionChange` function.

```
const [allSelectedRows, setAllSelectedRows] = useState([]);

onSelectionChange={(rows) => {
  setAllSelectedRows([...rows]);
}}
```

After that I generated a diff (with `deep-object-diff`) to see what was changed in those selected rows, generated an array with the new data and updated the state.

```
editable={{
  isEditable: (rowData) => data[rowData.tableData.id].Locked !== true,
  onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    const dataUpdateArray = [...data];
    if (allSelectedRows.length && allSelectedRows.includes(oldData)) {// if there is multiple checkboxes selected
      const updatedData = updatedDiff(oldData, newData);
      allSelectedRows.map((item) => {
        return Object.assign(dataUpdateArray[item.tableData.id], updatedData);
      });
    } else {// if there is no selected checkbox, you are editing a non-checked row
      dataUpdateArray[oldData.tableData.id] = newData;
    }
    setData([...dataUpdateArray]);
    resolve();
  }),
}}
```

For more details in the implementation, here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-bulk-edit?file=src/App.js) with all the necessary code to achieve this feature.